# Как сделать перенос текста

Tags: html, php, css, javascript

Не знаю как сделать перенос текста в котором есть HTML теги. Делаю чат, и при написании сообщения делаю перенос строки, все правильно, но нужно чтобы смайлики идущие подряд не переводились на новую строку, то есть должно быть так:
[image][image][image][image]

А у меня выводит так:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Вот код php для переноса:

```
function Splitter($str,$col,$pos=0)
{
    $arr = array();
    $found = false;
    for($i=$pos;$i<mb_strlen($str);$i++)
    {
    if($str[$i]==" " || $str[$i]=="\n" || $str[$i]=="\r")  $found=true;

        if($i!=0)
        if($i%$col==0)
        {
            if($found==false)
            {
                array_push($arr,$i);
            }
            $found = false; 
            }

        }
    for($i = 0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    {
        $s1=mb_substr($str,0,$arr[$i]);
    $s2=mb_substr($str,$arr[$i],mb_strlen($str)-$arr[$i]+1);
        $str = $s1."\r\n".$s2;
        }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема в css. Попробуйте прописать вашим изображениям свойство display: inline;

Comment: или float: left;

Comment: Ага спасибо большое помогло!!!